# How to convert Erlang sys.config into Elixir config.exs?

Tags: erlang, elixir

This is just probably easy one.
For example this sys.config into mix config.exs:

```
{gsms, [{interfaces,
  [
   {gsms_0705, 1, [{device,"/dev/tty.usbserial-FTF5DP2J"},
           {bnumber, "<phone-number>"},{baud,19200},
           {reopen_timeout, 5000}]}
   {gsms_0705, 2, [{device,"/dev/tty.HUAWEIMobile-Pcui"},
           {bnumber, "<phone-number>"},
           {reopen_timeout, 5000}]}
   {gsms_0705, 3, [{device, "/dev/tty.usbserial"},
          {bnumber, "<phone-number>"},
          {baud, 9600}]}
  ]}
]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you fix the syntax errors (missing commas) and add the mandatory trailing dot, you can even parse the Erlang term from Elixir and let the parser do the conversion for you:

```
erlang_term = '{gsms, [{interfaces, [
  {gsms_0705, 1, [{device,"/dev/tty.usbserial-FTF5DP2J"},
                  {bnumber, "<phone-number>"},{baud,19200},
                  {reopen_timeout, 5000}]},
  {gsms_0705, 2, [{device,"/dev/tty.HUAWEIMobile-Pcui"},
                  {bnumber, "<phone-number>"},
                  {reopen_timeout, 5000}]},
  {gsms_0705, 3, [{device, "/dev/tty.usbserial"},
                  {bnumber, "<phone-number>"},
                  {baud, 9600}]}
 ]}
]}.'

{:ok, tokens, _} = :erl_scan.string(erlang_term)
{:ok, result} = :erl_parse.parse_term(tokens)
IO.inspect result, limit: :infinity
```

This prints:

```
{:gsms,
 [interfaces: [{:gsms_0705, 1,
    [device: '/dev/tty.usbserial-FTF5DP2J', bnumber: '<phone-number>',
     baud: 19200, reopen_timeout: 5000]},
   {:gsms_0705, 2,
    [device: '/dev/tty.HUAWEIMobile-Pcui', bnumber: '<phone-number>',
     reopen_timeout: 5000]},
   {:gsms_0705, 3,
    [device: '/dev/tty.usbserial', bnumber: '<phone-number>', baud: 9600]}]]}
```

The first part of the tuple is the application name `:gsms`, the other part of the tuple is proplist containing the actual options. You can leave off the surrounding brackets and reformat this a bit and you will get:

```
config :gsms, interfaces: [
  {:gsms_0705, 1, [
    device: '/dev/tty.usbserial-FTF5DP2J',
    bnumber: '<phone-number>',
    baud: 19200,
    reopen_timeout: 5000]},
  {:gsms_0705, 2, [
    device: '/dev/tty.HUAWEIMobile-Pcui',
    bnumber: '<phone-number>',
    reopen_timeout: 5000]},
  {:gsms_0705, 3, [
    device: '/dev/tty.usbserial',
    bnumber: '<phone-number>',
    baud: 9600]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be it:

```
config :gsms, :interfaces, [
  {:gsms_0705, 1, [device: '/dev/tty.usbserial-FTF5DP2J',
                   bnumber: '<phone-number>',
                   baud: 19200,
                   reopen_timeout: 5000]},
  # and so on
]
```

where `:gsms` is the application you're configuring, `:interfaces` is the key you'll retrieve through `Application.get_env/2` (`Application.get_env(:gsms, :interfaces)`) and the list of `{:gsms_*, ...}` tuples is the value at that key.